# Firefox 4 beta won't allow dynamic creation of elements (Javascript) in new window?

Tags: javascript, window.open, appendchild, firefox4

It seems I can't really append elements to a new window in Firefox 4 beta (tested with beta 10).  It works fine in Firefox 3, Opera, Chrome and IE6, but it seems FF beta 4 broke it.

Here's a simple demonstration HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function c() {
    var o = window.open("", "", "status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=400,height=400");

    if(!o.document.body) {
        var b = o.document.createElement("body");
        o.document.body = o.document.appendChild(b);
    }
    var e = o.document.createElement("div");
    o.document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.innerHTML="abc";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:c();">abc</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, it's a page with a link, when clicked, pops up a new window with the text "abc" in it.
In Firefox beta 4, it pops up with the window, but nothing is displayed in it.  Using Firebug, it appears the nodes are created, but everything under the  tag, (including the  tag itself) is faded out in the tree, similar to invisible elements.  However, the computed CSS show that display and visibility styles are fine.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make it work in Firefox beta 4?

Comment: Does it need to? The idea of it being beta is an acknowledgement that it's not finished and that it will contain bugs. I would report it as a bug using the Feedback button in the browser and focus on getting your applications and sites working on full release browsers. There are plenty of issues with released browsers (ahem, I'm looking at you IE) without worrying about a buggy release.

Comment: I agree with you about the beta statement, however, what I'm perhaps more curious about, is whether it really is a bug on Firefox's side, or whether it's a new implementation which will stay.

Is there an issue in my code I'm not aware of? (for example)

Comment: Probably worth searching at bugzilla.mozilla.org, and raising a bug if you don't find anything similar.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore with the final either, from what I've tested. Did you file a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=637644), a fix should have been pushed to the repository, some days after the release of 4.0. This means that this behavior is expected to be fixed in next version of Firefox.